Hello, im trying to update my wifi driver no pci.id has showed on the list
Recently I've replaced my Windows 10 operating system to a Lubuntu operating system. However the wifi isnt working. After I've searched up this site and found a thread that is mostly helpful
I realized the list I was brought to of pci.ids- my driver isn't listed on it.
My ID is [14e4:1692] Rev 01
The computer is a pretty old model.

You've not told us what Lubuntu release you're using, so we can't yet provide any specific help. Did you follow any guides, eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide where 3.1 lets you detect the device you're using (chipset matters with Linux; what ID you provided is of limited value without additional detail)

LXQt version 1.4.0, I'm new to Linux.. but I am determined to learn.

LXQt is your desktop, and not your Lubuntu/Ubuntu release. Ubuntu releases are year.month in format, where the latest release is Lubuntu 24.10 or the 2024-October release.  You can upgrade your LXQt version via backports; so desktop (LXQt) version isn't reliable. You maybe using Lubuntu 24.04 LTS for example (2024-April release). At terminal you can use lsb_release -a or run neofetch at terminal for clues; or cat /etc/os-release etc ... (many ways in fact)

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS release 24.04, OS Lubunto
